# Rails - Issues Downloading S3 File using Fog/Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have a Rails application where I am storing a file on S3 using Fog/Carrierwave. When I go to download the file, I do not get the expected results. My code is the following:

```
v_file_name = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/{bucket}/{file}.pdf"

data = open(URI.parse(URI.encode(v_file_name)))

send_data data, :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'attachment', :filename => "{filename}.pdf"
```

I expect to get the download file dialog, but I get redirected in the browser to a page that begins with:

```
%PDF-1.3 %���� 1 0 obj << /Creator /Producer >> endobj 2 0 obj....
```

And ending in:

```
..... << /Size 10 /Root 2 0 R /Info 1 0 R >> startxref 25361 %%EOF
```

This code had previously been working, but has suddenly stopped working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. Problem was that I had implemented Turbolinks mid-project. Apparently Turbolinks breaks send_file & send_data in Rails. You can disable Turbolinks by adding "data-turbolinks='false'" to the link. This fixed it!